# Generating a Placemark (Google Earth) via information link

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, google-maps-api, google-earth

I'm using the ArcGIS JavaScript API.

I'd like to have an infowindow pop up that has a link to a downloadable KML placemark. Is this possible without pre-generating thousands of individual KML files?

Comment: I don,t think so it is possible, because Google earth provides only KML file.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. Can you please edit this question to include further details? What are you clicking on (eg, points within a feature layer) and what will the KML placemark contain?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).